# Beautifulsoup: How to get data from "window.__INITIAL_STATE__="

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How do I remove the "window.__INITIAL_STATE__=" and get the data from there?

I also don't need the data from  "window.__CONFIG__=" or "window.__USER_ID__="

Preferable make it JSON.

I have this code:

```
def html():
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), "html.parser")
    results = soup.select_one("script:-soup-contains('user_id')").string
    print(results)
```

And I get this response:

```
window.__INITIAL_STATE__={"room_info":{"my_id":45316761,"user_id":45316761,"loginname":"ahmad  Talent","status":10,"avatar":"https://nono-vpic-dl.akamaized.net/download/file/fra/nonolive-fra/nnphotos/45316761/7acc36198d61d535b556b5c9da4722a8.jpg","intro":"","anchor_group":["official_idol"],"anchor_intro":"تحدي الوكالة الاول الي اليوم الساعة ١٠ المسا بتوقيت سوريا","anchor_live":13,"pic":"https://nono-vpic-dl.akamaized.net/download/file/fra/nonolive-fra/imgs/3f95b611-bce2-4090-a354-74884b986105.jpg","fans":204,"exp":20673.649999999998,"level":49,"location":"Iran","country":"Iran","finance_country":"Syria","user_cluster":"aws_singapore"},"competition_live_room_list":[18433562,23281295,34344391,47277372,47256825,54286750,47255406,47353920,47256699,47795451,47262679,8646078,23419136,21453881,29813714,29710653,47262066,29368045,13938893,48391752,14673269,29333298,18485050,20545338,14485392,19220336,14597081,32203926,32284062,15130785,47543990,8623919,34033944,34030962,34099216,34403020,19973173,12376400,35225245,35303307,35277251,35357151,35397160,35157680,35486592,35517567,35517948,35530929,26480251,35541332,19267293,35791502,17367640,35003909,35857349,35684312,36294570,35858792,8181931,8181894,8181904,20519246,100008,36155173,36346677,36641437,36641273,36639480,36641374,36639155,36643700,36671965,37993657,37209374,31627285,37397273,38191007,34969242,8021848,37256644,38890560,35679023,35963867,35678785,35664149,35678453,36146858,38566654,47623047,38565866,33489767,38566762,40605811,37683851,36172817,36114494,37669650,40589540,36277491,41085963,38965463,38575592,39590981,36771882,33514817,37409947,37557443,38814672,36878613,39786744,38985315,40227952,39768448,39597105,2880999,745773,43248166,40693308,38018122,36730051,37930534,42377740,36912971,38283433,47397760,48544218,47928342,47288183,34803161,47353280,47660138,47851530,36240127,41677978,31433574,34134849,48223842,44517516,41686787,44084034,32136191,30911886,32764558],"default_title":"Nonolive - Game and Video Live Streaming"};
        window.__CONFIG__={"mwebsvr":"https://mob.nonolive.com","pcwebsvr":"https://www.nonolive.com","dispatchersvr":"https://disp.nonolive.com","dispatcher_env":"","cookie_domain":"nonolive.com","front_end_env":"production"};
        window.__USER_ID__= 45316761 ;
```

I know it can be done using regex but I have no clue how to do that. It's to complicated for me. Is there any other way?

If not, I would appreciate if someone could help me out with the regex part.

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: You need to execute the JavaScript. Use Selenium WebDriver rather than BS4.

Comment: @AndrejKesely https://www.nonolive.com/45316761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data using the `re`/`json` modules:

```
import re
import json
import requests

url = "https://nonolive.com/45316761"

html_doc = requests.get(url).text
data = re.search(r"window\.__INITIAL_STATE__=(.*?);", html_doc).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

# pretty print the data:
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "room_info": {
        "my_id": 45316761,
        "user_id": 45316761,
        "loginname": "ahmad  Talent\ud83c\udfac",
        "status": 10,
        "avatar": "https://nono-vpic-dl.akamaized.net/download/file/fra/nonolive-fra/nnphotos/45316761/7acc36198d61d535b556b5c9da4722a8.jpg",
        "intro": "",
        "anchor_group": [
            "official_idol"
        ],
        "anchor_intro": "\u062a\u062d\u062f\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0648\u0643\u0627\u0644\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0627\u0648\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u064a \u0627\u0644\u064a\u0648\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0627\u0639\u0629 \u0661\u0660 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0633\u0627 \u0628\u062a\u0648\u0642\u064a\u062a \u0633\u0648\u0631\u064a\u0627",
        "anchor_live": 13,
        "pic": "https://nono-vpic-dl.akamaized.net/download/file/fra/nonolive-fra/imgs/3f95b611-bce2-4090-a354-74884b986105.jpg",
        "fans": 204,
        "exp": 20683.416666666664,
        "level": 49,
        "location": "Iran",
        "country": "Iran",
        "finance_country": "Syria",
        "user_cluster": "aws_singapore"
    },
    "competition_live_room_list": [
        18433562,
        23281295,
        34344391,
        47277372,
        47256825,
        54286750,
        47255406,
        47353920,
        47256699,
        47795451,
        47262679,
        8646078,
        23419136,
        21453881,
        29813714,
        29710653,
        47262066,
        29368045,
        13938893,
        48391752,
        14673269,
        29333298,
        18485050,
        20545338,
        14485392,
        19220336,
        14597081,
        32203926,
        32284062,
        15130785,
        47543990,
        8623919,
        34033944,
        34030962,
        34099216,
        34403020,
        19973173,
        12376400,
        35225245,
        35303307,
        35277251,
        35357151,
        35397160,
        35157680,
        35486592,
        35517567,
        35517948,
        35530929,
        26480251,
        35541332,
        19267293,
        35791502,
        17367640,
        35003909,
        35857349,
        35684312,
        36294570,
        35858792,
        8181931,
        8181894,
        8181904,
        20519246,
        100008,
        36155173,
        36346677,
        36641437,
        36641273,
        36639480,
        36641374,
        36639155,
        36643700,
        36671965,
        37993657,
        37209374,
        31627285,
        37397273,
        38191007,
        34969242,
        8021848,
        37256644,
        38890560,
        35679023,
        35963867,
        35678785,
        35664149,
        35678453,
        36146858,
        38566654,
        47623047,
        38565866,
        33489767,
        38566762,
        40605811,
        37683851,
        36172817,
        36114494,
        37669650,
        40589540,
        36277491,
        41085963,
        38965463,
        38575592,
        39590981,
        36771882,
        33514817,
        37409947,
        37557443,
        38814672,
        36878613,
        39786744,
        38985315,
        40227952,
        39768448,
        39597105,
        2880999,
        745773,
        43248166,
        40693308,
        38018122,
        36730051,
        37930534,
        42377740,
        36912971,
        38283433,
        47397760,
        48544218,
        47928342,
        47288183,
        34803161,
        47353280,
        47660138,
        47851530,
        36240127,
        41677978,
        31433574,
        34134849,
        48223842,
        44517516,
        41686787,
        44084034,
        32136191,
        30911886,
        32764558
    ],
    "default_title": "Nonolive - Game and Video Live Streaming"
}
```