# How to correcly split the BeautifulSoup response to JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get data from a website with urllib and convert it to json.

My code looks like this.

```
username = "itsahardday"
url = "https://likee.video/@" + username # profile url - https://likee.video/account_name

def get_profile_html():
    '''
    Get profile data from HTML - https://likee.video/account_name
    :return:
    '''
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), "html.parser")
    results = soup.select_one("script:-soup-contains('userinfo')").string
    print(results)
    return results # add return

res=get_profile_html() # save the result
json_response = json.loads(res.split(";")[0].split("window.data =")[1])['userinfo']

print(json_response)
```

It works fine.

The issue is, when a "nick_name" in the response contains a ";" I guess. In example if `username = "887573847"`.

I get the following error:

```
json_response = json.loads(res.split(";")[0].split("window.data =")[1])['userinfo']

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 65 (char 64)
```

How do I fix this?

In advance, thank you for your kind help!

(I didn't know how to phrase the Title, so please help me rephrase it if it ain't specific to the question.)

Comment: You can use answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67203717/beautifulsoup-how-to-get-data-from-window-initial-state and change regex to `data = re.search(r"window\.data = (.*);", html_doc).group(1)`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you can extract the JSON from the `script` tag with the `re` package.

Here's how:

```py
import json
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0",
}

url = "https://likee.video/@itsahardday"  # profile url - https://likee.video/account_name


def get_profile_html():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, "html.parser")
    return soup.select_one("script:-soup-contains('userinfo')").string


json_response = json.loads(
    re.search(r"window\.data = (.*);", get_profile_html()).group(1)
)['userinfo']
print(json.dumps(json_response, indent=2))
```

Output:

```json
{
  "uid": "2927754396",
  "yyuid": "itsahardday",
  "nick_name": "ID:882832553",
  "user_name": "itsahardday",
  "data1": "https://img.like.video/asia_live/3s3/275Ldk.png?likee_official=1",
  "birthday": "1982-6-6",
  "exactCountryCode": "US",
  "bigUrl": "https://img.like.video/asia_live/3s2/06SqL8c.png?likee_official=1",
  "bio": "",
  "logo": [],
  "gender": 2,
  "pendant": {
    "id": "",
    "name": "",
    "url": ""
  },
  "PGC": "",
  "likeeId": "itsahardday",
  "allLikeCount": 0,
  "fansCount": 4,
  "followCount": 6,
  "age": 39,
  "constellation": "Gemini"
}
```